# If $G$ is $P$-generic over $V$ and $G^*$ is $j''P$-generic over $M$ then $j$ can be extended to $V[G]$.

Tags: set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

I've seen the following result:

> For elementary $j$, if $G$ is $P$-generic over $V$ and $G^*$ is $j(P)$-generic over $M$ and $j''G\subseteq G^*$ then $j$ can be extended to elementary $j:V[G]\rightarrow M[G^*]$.

This can be proven as:

For $x\in V[G]$ let $\tau$ by a name such that $\tau_G=x$ and define $j(x)=j(\tau)_{G^*}$. Let $x_1,..,x_n\in V$ and $\tau_1,..\tau_n$ be names for the $x_i$.
$$V[G]\models\phi(x_1,..x_n)$$
$$\implies p\Vdash \phi(\tau_1,..,\tau_n)\text{ for some } p\in G$$
$$\implies j(p)\Vdash \phi(j(\tau_1),..,j(\tau_n))$$
$$\implies M[G^*]\models \phi(j(x_1),..,j(x_n))$$

The last implication using the fact that $j(p)\in G^*$. Then substituting $\neg\phi$ for $\phi$ we get the iff.

I can't find where the fact that $G^*$ is $j(P)$ generic is used in the proof. As it seems to me that finding a $G^*$ that is $j''P$ generic would be enough for this proof to work and so we could always extend $j$ to $V[G]$ as $j''G$ will always be $j''P$ generic over $M$.

My question is: where is this fact used in the proof above?

I can see however that the claim:

> If $G$ is $P$-generic over $V$ and $G^*$ is $j''P$-generic over $M$ then $j$ can be extended to $V[G]\rightarrow M[G^*]$

can't be true as $V[G]$ will satisfy that some filter intersects every dense set in $P$ and $M[G^*]$ will probably not satisfy that some filter intersects every dense set in $j(P)$.

(Like for example if $crit(j)=\kappa$ and $P$ is the Cohen forcing $Fn(\kappa,2).$ Where $j''P$ is just $P$ but $j(P)$ is $Fn(j(\kappa),2)$  and $j''G$ is definitely not $j(P)$-generic over $M$.)

Comment: I don't see why people vote to close this as unclear.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line of the displayed math be $M[G^*]\models\dots$ rather than $M[G^*]\Vdash\dots$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, how can you justify that $j''P$ is even an element of $M$ in order for $G^*$ to be $M$-generic for it?

Moreover, how do you justify that $M[G^*]\models\phi(j(x))$ without appealing to the truth lemma? If $G^*$ is not $M$-generic, then why should $M[G^*]$ be a transitive [class] model of set theory?

Finally, we know that $V$ is definable in $V[G]$, and therefore $M$ should be definable in $M[G^*]$ by elementarity. So $V[G]$ satisfies that it is a generic extension of $V$ by the forcing $P$ with the filter $G$. Therefore $M[G^*]$ should also satisfy something similar, but applying $j$ to the whole thing gives us $j(P)$ and not $j''P$.

Comment: I would prefer the statement of the result to say $ j$ can be extended to  elementary $ j^*:V[G]\to M[G^*]$... In the first sentence of the proof,  we should define $j^*(x)=j(\tau)_{G^*}.$   If $x\in V$ then $j(x)$ is already defined. We must then justify that $j^*(x)=j(x).$ And  that, in  general,  $j(\tau)$ is indeed a $ j(P) $ name over $M$. (Although these might be obvious (or "background material")

Comment: Well, if $x$ is in $V$ take $\tau$ to be the canonical name for $x$.

Comment: Yes I thought we  should take the canonical name but that's not was in the proof presented.  .. &  I too don't know why this Q  would be voted to be closed.

Comment: Admittedly, I don't quite know where this proof is from and I've learned these topics from Menachem Magidor in several courses he gave on the topic while I was a student in Jerusalem. The point is that ultimately you need to argue that this definition doesn't depend on the choice of name. Using the canonical names you show that it extends the ground model embedding, but before that you need to show that it is a well-defined embedding.

Comment: Looking at your answer more closely I have some extra questions. Assuming that $j''P$ is in fact an element of $M$ (as in the example in my question) why can't it be extended to $V[G]\rightarrow M[G]$. I don't understand the use of the truth lemma here. By this I mean I don't understand why if the filter is $j(P)$-generic the truth lemma lets the proof in my question go through, but if the filter is $j''P$-generic then it does not.

Comment: @JPLK: The point is that you want to be able and extend the embedding, and so you need to tell what is $j(G)$, and by elementarity it should be $M$-generic over $j(P)$. Look at something like $2^{<\kappa}$, $j(2^<\kappa)=2^{<j(\kappa)}$ and $j''2^{<\kappa}=2^{<\kappa}$. But now you need a $j(\kappa)$-sequence, and not just a $\kappa$-sequence in order to interpret something like $j(\dot G)$, the canonical name for the generic.